# Jquery : Find nearest Div on li mouseenter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am trying to find a  particular div on hover of an li , Below is my html structure

```
<ul class="filters_ul">
  <li>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <label class="container-check-single-filter">Sort By Date Created</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="row" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="arrow_up arrow_up_grey" ng-click="set_sort_vals('date','asc')">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="arrow_down arrow_down_grey" ng-click="set_sort_vals('date','desc')">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
  </li>

</ul>
```

Upon hovering li i need to find **arrow_down_grey** and change its background image

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use `hover()` method of jquery for move hover event then find the closest div by class and id like below

```
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).find('.arrow_down_grey').css('backgroundImage',"url('https://www.aviary.com/img/photo-landscape.jpg')");
  }, function() {
    
  }
);
```

Comment: `.closest()` traverses _up_ the DOM tree, from the starting element. The `.arrow_down_grey` element is not _above_ the `li` in the DOM here, it is a _descendant_ of the `li`. This should be `$( this ).find('.arrow_down_grey')` instead.